# Entity Framework .Include Load Tables Joined in Different Context

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0

Quite new with LINQ. I am wondering how I would be able to achieve this.

I have the following table classes defined:

```
public partial class Cars
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public long CarModelID { get; set; }

    public virtual CarModel CarModel { get; set; }
}

public partial class CarModel
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public long StockID { get; set; }
}

public partial class Stock
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string StockName { get; set; }
}
```

There's also a defined extension for the class Cars (Cars.extension.cs):

```
public partial class Cars
{
    public List<Stock> StockList { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get all the `Cars`, `CarModel` and (List of) `Stocks` via the following query:

```
var query = (from cars in Context.Cars.Include("CarModel").Include("StockList")
                         select cars).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is giving me an error:

> ***"A Specified Include Path is not Valid. The Entity Type Cars does not declare a Navigation Property with the name 'StockList'"***

How would I be constructing my LINQ query such it would include possibly the list of `Stocks` based on a `CarModel` based off `Cars`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Include` method is adhering to FluentAPI principles, that means further `Include()` calls are still in the context of the parent entity (`Cars`) and not in the previously included `CarModel`.

What you need is:

```
Cars.Include("CarModel.StockList")
```

Or

```
Cars.Include(x => x.CarModel.StockList)
```